# MultiRequestHandler not working in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm was trying to run multiple queries in a single go then I came across something called MultiRequestHandler. I had put request handler in the solrconfig.xml file and restarted the solr.

```
<requestHandler name="/multi" class="solr.MultiRequestHandler"/>
```

I'm getting the error

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Error loading class 'solr.MultiRequestHandler'

My version of Solr is 5.4.0. Does my version of Solr doesnot support MultiRequestHandler?

Answer (score 0):

There never was a MultiRequestHandler added to Solr. The [ticket tracking its addition](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093) were resolved as Won't fix.

[The patch is available on Github](https://github.com/nicolaihald/lucene-solr-multi-request-handler), but hasn't been updated in three years - so it might not apply cleanly to 5.4.x.

Newer versions of Solr do however have Streaming Expressions, which could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh for your response. But Streaming Expressions are for SolrCloud. I'm working with normal Solr with a single Port.Any other alternative?

Comment: @Zeeshan We do the queries in parallel from the query layer, making x number of HTTP requests simulatenous

Comment: I see that it is using zookeeper server in the queries in Streaming expression. I'm currently not using any zookeeper server with solr in my application.

Comment: @Zeeshan Streaming Expressions is for SolrCloud installations. Use parallell queries if you're just using a single Solr server (or can't rewrite it as a Streaming Expression).